# twitter "Read, Write and Direct Messages" access 

Tags: twitter

Due to twitter, `Read, Write and Direct Messages` had been changed.

http://blog.twitter.com/2011/05/mission-permission.html

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/application-permission-model

They said by the end of June 30.

As I didn't edit permission upgrade for my app, what can I do how to rescue my app to access DM,etc?

I already asked twitter, still waiting answer.

Any suggestion or any ways round?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your app settings.

Click here -> https://dev.twitter.com/apps -> click on app -> click on settings tab -> scroll down to application type.

Then set it to `Read, Write and Access direct messages`. Save

That's all.